# iOS what to do instead of polling for near real-time data?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm developing an iPhone (and later Android) app that has real-time features, i.e. when one user posts something others will see it (depending on where they are in the app).

When implementing this in iOS one must keep in mind that network activity takes up lots of battery power.

The [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html) says "Connect to external network servers only when needed, and do not poll those servers."

How then is it possible for apps to have near real-time updated information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **Push Notification Service**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

This way, your application acts as a listener and can react to new Notifications that carry customized Payloads of data received by a server. even when it's running on background or not running at all.

Comment: Cool, do you think the Push Notification Service would be suitable even if there were frequent notifications (for example in a chat app)? Also is there an elegant way to have it only send notifications when the app is running in the foreground?

Comment: 1. For a chat app you would use a connection that is kept alive, i would use a tcp client. 2. You can choose to ignore push messeges that were received while the app was in background

Comment: One thing to take note is that push notifications are not 100% guaranteed reliable. So you'd need a backup mechanism.

Comment: You can't easily say "only send notifications when the app in the foreground", but you can send notifications that will not be displayed to the user at all. If your app is open, you'll get a callback, otherwise the notification won't be displayed to the user. Just don't put anything in the "aps" dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

For a foreground app, Open a read socket, and set an asynchronous delegate callback for data available.  Don't send any data to these sockets unless you have a new post ready to send.

Comment: Would a socket not drain the battery excessively?

Comment: Battery power?  More than not being able to communicate promptly or at all.  Less than useless polling for non-existent messages.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1), as already known from popular applications like [WhatsApp](http://www.whatsapp.com) (also a chat application).

From the docs:

> When new data for an application arrives, the provider prepares and
>   sends a notification through the channel to APNs, which pushes the
>   notification to the target device.

Comment: So does WhatsApp use Apple Push Notification Service for every message people send to you, even when the app is actually open?

Comment: I don't exactly know which way they are going when the app is already open. For this purpose, `stomp` could be an alternative: http://code.google.com/p/stompframework/

Comment: When the app is open, the notifications get delivered to the app in a callback, but they aren't displayed to the user. So yes, even when the app is open they're likely using the same mechanism

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using XMPP. Check out https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework for iOS.